# Как при нажатии кнопки получить блок div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на "кнопку" на сайте под кнопкой появлялся блок DiV с готовым текстом каким-либо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У блока, который ты хочешь открывать ставишь display: nonе. При помощи js ставишь обработчик на кнопку, который при нажатии изменяет display: none на display: block. Что-то типа этого:

```js
function viewDiv(){
  document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
};
```

```css
#div1{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click" onmousedown="viewDiv()">
<div id="div1">Блок</div>
```

Comment: `fixed`-то зачем? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy случайно написал. Сейчас изменю. Спасибо.

Comment: А почему `onmousedown`? Т. е. 1. почему такая устаревшая форма добавления обработчика? и 2. почему mousedown вместо click?

Comment: Если не сложно, то можете реализовать актуальную форму обработчика?

Answer (score 3):

Вот тоже интересный пример(Jquery)

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $(".block_with_text").fadeToggle(100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Кликни по мне</button>
<div class="block_with_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно и без js обойтись, это зависит от конкретной задачи и возможностей.
Например, с помощью скрытого чекбокса и метки, которая будет выступать псевдокопкой, переключать видимость DIVа:

```css
.text,
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .text {
  display: block;
}

/* Стилизация псевдокнопки */
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="pseudoBtn" class="btn">"Кнопка"</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="pseudoBtn">
<div class="text">Готовый текст</div>
```